# AS3: How can I access a movieclip in a different scene?

Tags: flash, flash-cs3, actionscript-3

I want to access a MovieClip in another scene than I'm currently in.

More specific I want to set a TextField to a certain value from a "preloader"-scene. This is for handling totally dynamic language phrases. Maybe this is the wrong way.

I'm loading a XML with language phrases that I want to replace the textfields with.

We could do this by altering all MovieClips, but I think this could be a smart solution, if it's possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747770/flash-as3-how-do-i-access-display-object-in-other-frames-aka-a-frame-other-tha/2752212#2752212) (internally, scenes are just frames as far as Flash is concerned, so that answer applies to you as well). MovieClips that don't exist in the current frame haven't been instantiated yet, so they can't be accessed - the solution is either to move to the frame where the target is, to move the target so that it exists in the current frame (even if it's offstage), or to delay initializing the target until the frame where it gets instantiated.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms my thesis. My work around is to add a function to every movieclip that calls a function in root. It works, but it's not the definition beauty.